# Getting "Fatal error: Cannot access empty property" in my controller using the Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

This is the bit of code, it's a base class for my controller that initializes all common values.  The file is in my models folder if that makes a difference.  The weird thing is it works locally in MAMP where I'm developing, but not on the server.  I'm thinking it may be a configuration issue?

```
<?php
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Controller_Action');

class BaseController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    protected $auth;
    protected $current_user;
    protected $db;

    protected function initialize_values()
    {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        if($auth->hasIdentity())
        {
            $this->$current_user = $auth->getIdentity();
            $this->view->user = $this->$current_user;
        }

        $this->db = Zend_Registry::get('dbAdapter');

        $this->view->controller_name = $this->_request->getControllerName();
        $this->view->view_name = $this->_request->getActionName();
    }
}
```

I get it on the line that is first in the if statement

```
$this->$current_user = $auth->getIdentity();
```

I understood this error to mean it was trying to access a property or method that doesn't exist.  In this case I know that exists

Comment: Can you do a var_dump($auth->getIdentity()); ?

Comment: Do What @AurelioDeRosa has said and see what is in it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `$this->$current_user`, shouldn't you use `$this->current_user`

`$current_user` is null in your case, hence the error.

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple that I was overlooking, thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Jhorra
If you use $this->$current_user you are referencing to a property of the object $this, an the property you are trying to access is whatever $current_user was set to.

Let's say you have something like this:

```
$current_user = 'name';
$this->$current_user; //this is the same as $this->name
```

But in your case you are assigning some value to $current_user and is possible that that value is not a property of the $this object.